# How to add debounce time to validation service Angular2?

Tags: angular, validation, timer

I have a problem where I want to validate a username textfield however each keypress is sending an HTTP request and its kinda spammy, here is my current code:

```
lookupUser(username: string): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('User', sessionStorage.getItem('username'));
    headers.append('Token', sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    headers.append('AccessTime', sessionStorage.getItem('AccessTime'));
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get("URL" + username, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError) as Observable<any>;
};
```

The function itself

```
export function usernameTaken(userService: UserService) {
    return control => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            userService.lookupUser(control.value).subscribe(data => {
                if (data.username) {
                    resolve({ usernameTaken: true })
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            }, (err) => {
                console.log("in error" + err);
                if (err !== "404 - Not Found") {
                    resolve({ usernameTaken: true });
                } else {
                    resolve(null);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Where would I add my debounce timer if any? I tried adding it to the response service but it threw an error of undefined.

Comment: Can you build a plunker that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Every observable (so also the http.get) has the option to set debounceTime and debounce.

Answer (score 0):

Before you subscribe to your promise add `debounceTime(500)`.

```
export function usernameTaken(userService: UserService) {
   return control => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        userService.lookupUser(control.value).debounceTime(500).subscribe(data => {
            if (data.username) {
                resolve({ usernameTaken: true })
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("in error" + err);
            if (err !== "404 - Not Found") {
                resolve({ usernameTaken: true });
            } else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

In this case your service will wait `500 milliseconds (.5 second)` before it `subscribes` to data

Comment: The delay is happening but its still firing 10 times for a 10 character input. I'd like to simply send the request when input is done.

I tried adding a debounce time to both but its only delaying the 10 inputs

Answer (score 0):

Where is `lookupService` called? Are you using template-driven or reactive forms?

If you are subscribing to valueChanges on the input element, you could instead add the `debounceTime` there.

```
this.myControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(800).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: The request is still firing 10 times for a 10 character input. I'm using reactive forms.